# "programmatically" call the Sitecore Cortex Content Tagging feature

Tags: cortex

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1, I enabled `content tagging`, I want to programmatically apply the `content tagging` to a specific item. Is there a way to programmatically trigger the `Tag item` tab and pass the item to it for example by calling an API (if there is an OOTB API that does so) ?

[image]

**EDIT:**

I tried the IContentTaggingRunner and this was the output:

1] the data wasn't cleared as shown in the picture and its the same IDs in every Item.
2] the data is added in the semantics not the tag field.

Does anyone know the solution?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code for that button in the `TagContentCommand` class, you need to use the `IContentTaggingRunner` to call that. Here is an example taken from the command class for that button:

```
public class MyTaggingClass
{
    private readonly IContentTaggingRunner _contentTaggingRunner;

    public MyTaggingClass(IContentTaggingRunner contentTaggingRunner)
    {
        _contentTaggingRunner = contentTaggingRunner;
    }

    protected void RunTagging(Item contentItem)
    {
        using (new SecurityEnabler())
        {
            if (contentItem.Security.CanWrite((Account) Context.User))
            {
                _contentTaggingRunner.Run(contentItem, messageBus);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Warn(string.Format("Item '{0}' was not tagged. User doesn't have write access to it.", (object) contentItem.Paths.Path), (this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `IContentTaggingRunner.Run` method just takes the content item. If you want to run this from the UI, there is a message bus that you can use to update the UI too. Just look at the code for `TagContentCommand` to see how its used.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in the documentation on how to invoke in your solution: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/use-the-sitecore-cortex-content-tagging-framework-in-your-custom-solution.html

> Get the ContentTaggingRunner and MessageBusFactory  services as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> var ContentTaggingRunner = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContentTaggingRunner>();
> var MessageBusFactory = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMessageBusFactory>();
> ```
>
> Create a message bus. The UI can communicate with the process through
>   the message bus. You must also implement a custom message handler.
>
> ```
> var messageBus = MessageBusFactory.Create();
> var messageHandler = new CustomMessageHandler();
> messageBus.Subscribe(messageHandler);
> ```
>
> Pass the content item and message bus instance to the runner.
>
> `ContentTaggingRunner.Run(item, messageBus);`

Comment: i tried ur solution and i edited my question with the result.can you please check it and advise?

Comment: Hi @AmiraElEwady, if you have a new question, please post a new question. If you felt my answer answered your original question, that is great, but it is best practice not to change the goal of a question as it invalidates previously provided answers.